# How to sort ArrayList of integers without regardless of positive and negative values

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, comparable

Let suppose that we have some ArrayList with values:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(40);
list.add(5);
list.add(-5);
list.add(-1);
list.add(10);
list.add(-12);
```

The natural sorting will be: [-12,-5,-1,5,10] with Collections.sort(list)

But how can I "ignore" (I'm sorry for definition) the negative and positive values and I get the following result: [-1,-5,5,10,-12]?

Previously thanks for spare time for my question.

Comment: Write a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that uses [`Math.abs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-).

Comment: have you done any kind of research?

Comment: @KevinWallis obviously he tried sort it via `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and for spend time fro me. Have a nice day.

Comment: I nominate to reopen this question, as sorting list has slightly different ways and more convenient approaches in java-8 than sorting simple arrays

Comment: @Andremoniy By the power of Mjollnir, it is done!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the `Math.abs()` function:

```
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return Integer.compare(Math.abs(o1), Math.abs(o2));
        }
    });
```

Or a lambda for java-8:

```
Collections.sort(list,(o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(Math.abs(o1), Math.abs(o2)));
```

Or even more simple, there is ready an out-of-the-box comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(Math::abs));
```

And if we are talking about java-8 at least, the simplest one is just:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Math::abs));
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I was really stuck. Have a nice day.